# Create complex HTML in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Here is a typical problem. Imagine that you have a table of data, where you can add, update and delete rows dynamically (in ajax).
Your data table is complex, with many fields, dropdowns, textboxes, etc.

How would you create the rows in javascript ? I currently have a lot of JS/Jquery creating and populating nodes, but I find it quite ugly, and not very reusable.

My aspx is this :

```
<!-- table to contain the data -->
<table id="facetsTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <th>Label</th>
            <th>Display type</th>
            <th>Is filter</th>
            <th>Sort type</th>
            <th>&nbsp;</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
<br />

<!-- dropdown containing the facets to add -->
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="facetsToAddDdl">
    <asp:ListItem Text="" Value=""></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="facetAddButton" Text="[ADD]" />

<!-- hidden fields to contain both the current data and all the possible data -->
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="facetsSerializedHidden" />
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="allAttributesSerializedHidden" />
```

When loading, the code-behind just serializes the current data into `facetsSerializedHidden`. When saving, in deserializes it.

And the javascript is this :

```
var allAttributes = null;

/*****************************
* Adds a facet to the table
*****************************/
function facetAdd(data) {
    // build the table row
    var tr = $('<tr>');

    // "move" handle
    tr.append($('<td>').addClass('handle').append($('<img/>').attr('src', 'img/drag-drop.gif')));

    // label
    tr.append(
        $('<td>')
        .addClass('label')
        .text(data.attr.DefaultListLabel.DefaultValue + ' (' + data.attr.Code + ')')
        .append($('<input />').attr('type', 'hidden').attr('name', 'code').val(data.attr.Code)));

    // display type
    var disp = $('<select>').attr('name', 'displayType');
    // snip: fill options of the select
    if (data.facet && data.facet.DisplayType !== '') { disp.val(data.facet.DisplayType) }
    disp.change(function () { serializeFacets(); });
    tr.append($('<td>').append(disp));

    // ###### snip similar logic for the other fields ######

    // 'remove' image button
    var delImg = $('<img />').attr('src', 'img/delete.png');
    delImg.click(function () { facetRemove($(this)) });
    tr.append($('<td>').addClass('delete').append(delImg));

    // add the row to the table
    $('#facetsTable tbody').append(tr);
}

/*****************************
* Removes a facet from the table
*****************************/
function facetRemove(src) {
    var tr = src.parents('tr');
    var code = tr.find('[name=code]').val();
    var label = tr.find('td.label').text();

    // remove from table
    $(tr).remove();

    // add back item to dropdown list
    var drop = $('#<%= facetsToAddDdl.ClientID %>');
    drop.append($('<option>', { value: code, text: label }));

    // re-serialize
    serializeFacets();
}

/*****************************
* Serialize the facets
*****************************/
function serializeFacets() {
    var ser = [];
    var i = 0;
    $('#facetsTable tbody tr').each(function () {
        var facet = new Object();
        facet.Code = $(this).find('[name=code]').val();
        facet.Id = $(this).find('[name=code]').val();
        facet.DisplayType = $(this).find('[name=displayType]').val();
        facet.IsFilter = $(this).find('[name=isFilter]').prop('checked');
        facet.SortType = $(this).find('[name=sortType]').val();
        facet.Order = i;

        ser.push(facet);
        i++;
    });

    $('#<%= facetsSerializedHidden.ClientID %>').val(JSON.stringify(ser));
}

/*****************************
* Activate sorting on the table
*****************************/
function activateSorting() {
    $('#facetsTable tbody').sortable({
        stop: function () { serializeFacets(); },
        handle: ".handle"
    });
}

/*****************************
* Get the facet data from the attributes list
*****************************/
function getFacetData(code, existingFacet) {
    if (allAttributes === null) { return null; }

    for (var i = 0; i < allAttributes.length; i++) {
        if (allAttributes[i].Code === code) {
            var facet = {};
            if (existingFacet === null) {
                facet.Code = code;
                facet.Id = code;
                facet.Order = -1;
            } else {
                facet = existingFacet;
            }

            return { attr: allAttributes[i], facet: facet };
        }
    }

    return null;
}

$(function () {
    // read attributes list
    var allAttributesSerialized = $("#<%= allAttributesSerializedHidden.ClientID %>").val();
    if (allAttributesSerialized !== '' && allAttributesSerialized !== null) {
        allAttributes = JSON.parse(allAttributesSerialized);
    }

    // activate sorting on the table
    activateSorting();

    /*****************************
    * Initialize facets on load
    *****************************/
    var currentFacetsSerialized = $('#<%= facetsSerializedHidden.ClientID %>').val();
    if (currentFacetsSerialized !== '' && currentFacetsSerialized !== null) {
        var currentFacets = JSON.parse(currentFacetsSerialized);
        for (var i = 0; i < currentFacets.length; i++) {
            facetAdd(getFacetData(currentFacets[i].Code, currentFacets[i]));
        }
    }

    /*****************************
    * Add a facet to the table on button click
    *****************************/
    $("#<%= facetAddButton.ClientID %>").click(function () {
        var code = $('#<%= facetsToAddDdl.ClientID %>').val();

        if (code === null || code === '') { return false; }

        facetAdd(getFacetData(code, null));
        $('#<%= facetsToAddDdl.ClientID %> option:selected').remove();
        activateSorting();
        serializeFacets();

        return false;
    });
});
```

I would love to have my row's HTML in a user control that I could call in ajax (through a service for instance), so that I can create a row both in JS and in .net, but I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Start researching templating systems, and pick the one that suits _you_ the best.

Comment: What's currently "ugly" about it?  (Maybe this belongs on the Code Review site instead of Stack Overflow?)  I imagine I'd just create some template function in JavaScript which creates the row with a given set of values and just call that function any time I need to add a row.

Comment: This is quite an open question. Please narrow it down and post a [mcve] - unless I am wrong (then ignore me)

Comment: Typically you would use some kind of templating library for this. If you want to hard code it by hand, there's two schools of thought: Either create all the nodes with createElement/cloneNode and then append them. Or use strings and innerHTML. Most maintainable solution would be to create some functions that will do this for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use front end templating techniques. I provided a quick and dirty vanilla JS solution below, but you can get jQuery plugins (I see you have a jQuery tag on your question) and use templating languages to put some of the data-binding logic into the template. Angular.js may also be something of interest to check out.

```js
var templateText,
    generatedEl,
    anchorEl,
    obj;

// "JSON" data (could be loaded via AJAX)
obj = { 'text': 'Hello World', 'href': '#' };

// Get template text
templateText = document.getElementById('my-template').text.trim();

// Create a DIV and generate HTML within it
generatedEl = document.createElement('div')
generatedEl.innerHTML = templateText;

// Modify the HTML content with obj data
anchorEl = generatedEl.getElementsByTagName('a')[0];
anchorEl.text = obj.text;
anchorEl.href = '#';

// Insert generated HTML (assumes only one top-level element exists)
document.getElementById('my-container').appendChild(generatedEl.childNodes[0]);
```

```html
<!-- Container -->
<div id="my-container">
    
    <!-- HTML Template -->
    <script id="my-template" type="text/template">
        <div class="item">
            <a></a>
        </div>
    </script>
    
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Reading from [jQuery( html, attributes )](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/):

you can use a [PlainObject](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#PlainObject) to create the elements on the fly:

```js
$(function () {
  var obj = { 'id': 'anchor1', 'text': 'Hello World', href: '#' };
  
  $('<a>',obj).appendTo(document.body)

  console.log(document.getElementById('anchor1').outerHTML);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar issue before. The solution that worked for me was to just have a template JS function that'd get the current table row count, and then create all the HTML elements for that row, and then append them to the table. You can do this with an ASP generated table, or use a literal and generate the table on the back end using a `stringbuilder` (my preference).